# AmazonS3Client constructor in .Net Core throws when running under NETWORK_SERVICE (service fabric)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I need to upload some data to the S3 storage using dotnet-core service in the service fabric cluster (which is running as NETWORK_SERVICE).

In this scenario I am not able to construct the AmazonS3Client.

```
var s3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccountKey, awsSecret, RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
```

Throws:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.DeterminedCSMConfiguration' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner exception:
>
> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied.

I am using nugets:

- AWSSDK.S3 Version="3.3.24.3"
- AWSSDK.Core Version="3.3.27"

The code runs OK:

- Under dotnet framework 4.6.2 (net462) (in the same service fabric cluster)
- Under dotnet core, but run under regular user (not in service fabric)

**Questions:**

- Is it OK to use the AWS SDK nugets in dotnet core?
- What is the constructor looking for in C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile folder? I provided account key and secret, shouldn't it be enough?
- Is there some setting I am missing to workaround the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in AWSSDK.Core: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1097

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK is a dot net standart package that should work fine on Full Framework or DotNet Core, you can confirm that when you ran the application on your machine and it worked.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` is a folder used to store system profile information, similar to fodlers like `C:\users\username\`,

I would assume it is trying to *load or save* something in there because it is running as NetWork Service and is failing, I would try:

- Run the service as a local user in SF, instead of Network Service
- Check if all files are being copied correclty
- use the `AmazonS3Client` that receives an explicit `AmazonS3Config` instead
- Check if the DotNet core is installed in the server and the version in there is compatible with the one you are using

Comment: The code works OK when run on dotnet core as a standalone app as NetworkService (via PSExec). It also runs OK on dotnet core in SF on Linux. It looks like the issue is only dotnet core + windows SF cluster.

Comment: Can you then make sure it is running as Network Service in SF? Maybe the cluster is set to run as different profile! Have you tried to set to run as local user in the node?